# nested foreach loops returns only distinct

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

I have a database where each email address should belong to a unique customer, but I have many duplicates.  I used a sql query to list customer ID, email address pairs for each occurrence where there is more than one customer ID mapped to a single email address.  The result looks something like this (addresses changed to protect the innocent)

```
Customer ID   Email
101233        bob@myaddress.com
108993        bob@myaddress.com
113224        bob@myaddress.com
89223         mary@otherdomain.com
188223        mary@otherdomain.com
```

In c#, I populate this into a DataTable called dt with 722 rows.  I use this to make a second DataTable called distinctTbl with 344 rows containing only the distinct email addresses using this:

```
DataTable distinctTbl = dt.AsDataView().ToTable(true, "Email");
```

I am trying to use nested loops to make a list of integers (Customer ID) for each email address:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in distinctTbl.Rows)
{
    // for each email address:
    List<int> idNums = new List<int>();

    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows) 
    {
        // for every customerID / email pair in the original table
        if (myRow["Email"] == dr["Email"])
        {
            idNums.Add((int)myRow["CustomerID"]);
        }
    }

    // Do something with the List<int> before exiting outside loop
}
```

When I run this code, each List of integers contains exactly one value.  The value is correct, but there should be a minimum of two for each email address.  I have done enough debugging to figure out that it always correctly identifies the first one, but skips any subsequent matches.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but does somebody see what is happening?

Comment: http://www.elevenwinds.com/linq-distinctby-with-lambda-expression-parameter

Comment: what if you changed the inner loop `foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows) ` to a `for loop` so declare something like a column count 
`int iColCount = distinctTbl.Columns.Count;` then iterate over the column(s) for each row.. if not then declare a var intCnt = 0; outside of the inner foreach loop and then check if `myRow[intCnt]["Email] == (string)dr["Email"]` then add the necessary items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ditch the `foreach` loops.**

You can use Linq to get the information you're looking for more easily.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> emailIDs =
    dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
           .GroupBy(row => (string)row["Email"])
           .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key,
                         grp => grp.Select(row => (int)row["CustomerID"]).ToList());
```

Comment: I like it!  I was trying Linq initially but couldn't figure out the syntax of grouping everything this way.  This works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @ElementalPete The `GroupBy` method can be a little tricky at first because it doesn't just return a normal `IEnumerable` or a single element the way most Linq methods do. I feel like they also need a lot more `ToDictionary` overloads for convenience but in this case one of the existing ones worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

One quick and easy solution is to use a `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` instead of a list:

```
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> idNums = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        string email = myRow["Email"].ToString()
        if (idNums.ContainsKey(email))
        {
            idNums[email].Add((int)myRow["CustomerID"]);
        }
        else
        {
            idNums.Add(email, new List<int> { (int)myRow["CustomerID"] });
        }
    }
```

Now idNums will contain the list of id's associated with each email.

Comment: I opted to use the Linq query, but this seems to work fine too!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ElementalPete - One thing to keep in mind.  Since your data size is quite small, efficiency probably isn't an overriding concern.  However, if the data size gets to be really large, keep in mind the LINQ query iterates over the data twice and can present a performance hit on large data sets.